# Eclipse and Pydev Python

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to run Python using Pydev and Eclipse (Eclipse Standard/Eclipse Luna).
However, when I try to run a file, I get:

> This version of PyDev requires a newer version of Eclipse to run properly.
>   Please upgrade Eclipse or use an older version of PyDev.

(I got Pydev from http://pydev.org/updates)

I checked for Eclipse updates and I got "No updates were found", therefore:
how can I dowgrade PyDev to get a version which fits my Eclipse version?

Comment: What version of pydev are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Luna is definitely not the latest version of Eclipse. Go download a new Eclipse.

Comment: In other words "No updates were found *for Luna*". And Eclipse doesn't upgrade versions unless you actually add the update repositories (which sometimes breaks things, which is why that is not the default behavior)

Comment: I downloaded from Eclipse Neon Link, after that I chose, "Eclipse Standard" and the executable installed, by itself, "Eclipse Luna" . Should I select something different to "Eclipse Standard" ?

Comment: I would think the Neon installer installs Neon. I'm not sure, though, I just would use PyCharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Requisites**
>
> PyDev requires java 8 and Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) in order to run.

http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

You can't use Luna.

Answer (score 0):

tanks for your answers, navigating through the details (not in the standard display of options), The Neon version is named "Eclipse Platform" that made all the pieces work